# Making HTTPS requests in Python fails, but not HTTP

Tags: python, proxy, request

I am sitting behind a corporate proxy. The following code doesn't allow me to get content from an HTTPS site. The HTTP and HTTPS proxy are both passed through an HTTP proxy. Why am I not able to access the site?

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.theguardian.com'

proxies = {
    'http': 'http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@IP:PORT',
    'https': 'http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@IP:PORT'
}

# Create the session and set the proxies.
s = requests.Session()
s.proxies = proxies

# Make the HTTP request through the session.
r = s.get('https://www.cnbc.com')
r
```

The error message showing up is

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.cnbc.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

Comment: Any error message? You are aware that your code does not output anything?

Comment: @KlausD. please find the error message in the edit of the question

Comment: Ask your corporate IT how to make an SSL connection through the proxy. You might have install or [pass](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) a special SSL CA certificate.

Comment: @KlausD. I've spoke to people in my organisation. I have the SSL certificate at the ready. It needs to be injected manually with the get command. Is this something you have had to do before/know how to do?

Answer (score -2):

You should give a more detailed error message. It may be an SSL verification problem, please try to fetch like below.

```
requests.get('https://example.com', verify=False)
```

Comment: Please don't do that unless you are 100% percent sure that the target website is safe (And even then, don't do that). This is dangerous and expose your application to some serious security risks.

Comment: Of course, it is a security risk if you apply that to the production environment. However, this is the fastest way to see whether it is an SSL verification problem.